# Find most frequent path using network graphs?

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to represent visits data to my site as a network graph.

Im interested to know what is the most frequent group of nodes users take to get from node chicken to monkey.

The important thing is that I want user id to be tracked over the nodes in order to know what are the most frequent nodes a user takes to reach point A to point B.

Data i have looks like:

```
user_id visit_number previous_pagename current_pagename
abc     1            chicken           dog
abc     1            dog               cat
abc     1            cat               monkey
def     2            chicken           cat
def     2            cat               monkey
ghi     3            chicken           cat
ghi     3            cat               monkey

abc: [chicken - dog - cat - monkey]  -> 1
def & ghi: [chicken - cat - monkey]  -> 2
```

So the most frequent route is `[chicken - cat - monkey]`

I know we can use BFS or DFS to find shortest path but that doesn't take into consideration the user id or count. It doesnt track users over the different nodes.

I can save user id in the edge attributes and I can get the tuples of current_node and destination_node which is the `previous_pagename` and `current pagename`.

Is there any way to make use of the node attributes for what i want to accomplish?

Comment: You could put a weight on your edges corresponding to the inverse count of traversals. Then you can compute the shortest path in the weighted network between chicken and monkey to find the most commonly traveled route. If you want this count on a per user basis, you just have to store one weight per user in edge attributes and specify which one to use in the `weight` parameter of `shortest_path`.

Answer (score 1):

Given your definition of path can skip steps to find the frequently visited nodes in order, you'd be able to use the PrefixSpan algorithm: https://github.com/chuanconggao/PrefixSpan-py

It works pretty similarly to the Frequent Itemset

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).